# CSS: how to center a list with image

Tags: css

How do I center an unordered list that is divided with an image inside?

I want to achieve that the unordered list is one row, centered and also the image inside is centered so that the image divides the rest of the list in two halves (`topnav-left` and `topnav-right`).

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <div class="topnav-left">
    <li class="">
      <a class="toggle-nav" data-no-turbolink="true" href="Women">Women</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a class="toggle-nav" data-no-turbolink="true" href="Men">Men</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="/de/pages/stores">Stores</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="/de/pages/lifestyle">Lifestyle</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="nile-logo" style="">
    <li>
      <a href="/de"><img alt="Logo" src="http://img.logospectrum.com/dec/dummy-logo.jpg"></a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <li class="">
      <a class="toggle-account-nav" data-no-turbolink="true" href="/de/account">My Account</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cart">
        <a href="/de/cart">
              Warenkorb
</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a html="{:class=>&quot;open-wishlist&quot;}" href="/de/wishlist">WUNSCHLISTE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="language">
      <a class="language" href="/en/pages/imprint">EN</a>
      <a class="language" href="/fr/pages/imprint">FR</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
ul.nav { text-align: center; }

ul.nav li { display: inline-block; }
```

Here a codepen: [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGomQb)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...a `ul` can only have `li` as children...not divs.

Comment: Yes, it's not valid regarding the specification of HTML but all common browsers allow it and let you style the div as an child element of ul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `display:flex;` add this to add this,

```
ul {display:flex;justify-content: space-around;list-style-type: none;}

ul.nav li { flex:1; text-align: center; } /* Edit from comment by Paulie_D
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GjNZzR)

Comment: Yes, it's very close to my goal but the image doesn't look absolutely centered. Is there a way to position the image exactly in the middle of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pENYLZ

```
ul.nav li { 
  display: block;
 }
```

Or like this?:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAOoKN

```
ul.nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav li {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for your effort! I'm looking for a horizontally centered list like the one C Travel made. Sorry that I didn't make it clear enough.